# Проверка на дублирование элементов массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Господа, помоги с сей задачкой. Нужно проверить элемент массива MyReaderData.TagList[i].ToString() на дублирование :

```
private void HandleData(Symbol.RFID.ReaderData TheReaderData)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MyReaderData.TagList.TotalTags; i++)
    {
        string[] sItems = new string[] 
            {
                i.ToString(), 
                MyReaderData.TagList[i].ToString() 
            };
        this.ReaderDataListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(sItems));
     }
}
```

Comment: Исходными данными в этом методе являются RFID- метки, а точнее это GUID rfid - метки. И задача состоит в том, чтобы добавить в этот метод проверку, чтобы не считывать одну и ту же метку.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю что вы перебираете некий массив и хотите создать новый массив содержащий только уникальные метки плюс индекс метки из оригинального массива?

Comment: Bald56rus, верно.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы решить поставленную задачу можно воспользоваться средствами `Linq`

```
//Создаем список объектов
var rows1 = Enumerable.Range(1,50).Select(x=> Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
//Создаем частичную копию
var rows2 = rows1.Take(5);
//Объединяем что бы коллекция содержала дубликаты
var rows = rows1.Concat(rows2);

//Получаем уникальные записи и индексируем их
var results = rows.Distinct().Select((r, i)=> new {Index = i, Row = r});

foreach(var r in results)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Index: {0} Row: {1}", r.Index, r.Row));    

//если же необходимо проиндексировать изначальный список и получить первые элементы
//а дубликаты исключить то можно поступить так

var results2 = rows.OrderBy(x=>x)
    .Select((r,i)=>new {Index = i, Row = r})
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Row)
    .Select(x=>new {Index = x.First().Index, Row = x.Key});

foreach(var r in results2)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Index {0}      Row {1}", r.Index, r.Row));
```

что бы методы расширений `Select(), Distinct()` и прочие были доступны необходимо подключить следующее пространство имен `System.Linq;` при помощи директивы `using`

пример [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RH1gHy)

Comment: мне кажется или тут: `var results = rows.Distinct().Select((r, i)=> new {Index = i, Row = r});` индексы не в исходном массиве, а в уже отуникальненном? :-)

Comment: тут будут уникальные элементы. @Grundy а в result2 сначали индекс а потом получение уникальных элементов. если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: а зачем тогда индексы уникальных элементов из списка с **только** уникальными значениями? они же и будут идти 0,1,2,...

Comment: @Grundy там в самом начале принудительно примешиваются дубликаты. для демонстрации. а results / results2 - для того, чтобы показать разинцу подходов.

Comment: @PashaPash, `rows.Distinct()` возвращает список уникальных элементов, и по нему уже берется селект

Comment: @Grundy ну тс хотел с индексами а пример данных не привел пришлось импровизировать, делать тестовый массив, в задании не совсем понятно что хочет тс, и как написал PashaPash в ответе два варианта

Comment: @Grundy это два разных решения для двух разных вариантов прочтения задачи - в зависимости от того, что там считается индексом

Comment: не не не, после _Distinct_ индекс который сохраняется в селекте, не будет соответствовать индексу из исходно массива

Comment: из уточнения в вашем же комментарии: _новый массив содержащий только уникальные метки плюс **индекс метки из оригинального массива**_

Comment: @Grundy индексы для какой то цели необходимы ТС, смотрите вопрос(`for`). если он просто хочет получить уникальные элементы то ему подойдет result, и да в этом случае индексация не нужна. `result2` индексирует ***исходный*** массив и возвращает первую метку для не уникальных записей.

Comment: в _result_ индексируется не _исходный_ массив

Comment: @Grundy тс подтвердил 15 часов назад, ответу два дня. отсюда в ответе два варианта, я смог Вас убедить?!